# Desabilitar ação no mouse move C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou com um problema no meu código, eu tenho algumas ações no mouse move em C# e gostaria de desabilita-las. Sempre que eu arrasto o mouse para a listbox do meu form, ela já faz a ação, gostaria de deixar isso no click do mouse, mas estou com dificuldades, segue o código caso alguém possa ajudar eu agradeço.

```
private void lstColunasLayout2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  int index = lstColunasLayoutSecundario.IndexFromPoint(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
  ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
  if (index >= 0 && lb_item != null) {
    lb.SelectedIndex = index;
    AtualizaRelacaoColunas(lb);
    lb_item = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: So para esclarecer, tu queres esse mesmo código no evento click da listbox?

Comment: Não precisa ser exatamente o mesmo, gostaria de saber apenas como transpassar esse código para o click.

Comment: Pode aceitar uma resposta caso tenha satisfeito seu problema :)

Answer (score 1):

Remova a associação entre o evento `MouseMove` do listbox e o método `lstColunasLayout2_MouseMove`.

Para isso, exclua a seguinte linha do seu código:

```
    this.lstColunasLayout2.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.lstColunasLayout2_MouseMove);
```

Se você usou o Visual Studio para criar o form, provavelmente, essa linha de código estará dentro do arquivo "[NomeForm].Designer.cs"

Uma outra forma de fazer isso, se você estiver usando o Visual Studio, seria:

- Abrir o Form
- Selecionar o Listview
- Na janela Properties, clicar no botão eventos (botão com o ícone de um raio)
- Apagar o conteúdo do evento MouseMove

Comment: Resolveu amigo, parou de realizar a ação quando arrasta, transferi e alterei o código para dentro do click, e agora só clickando para funcionar. Agradecido.

Comment: Transferir o código de um evento para outro vai funcionar mas seria interessante desabilitar o evento que você não vai usar mais para evitar degradação do código ou possíveis erros no futuro.

Comment: Se resolveu o problema, por favor marque como resposta correta.